# Disable dropdownlist option with other dropdownlist option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, list, dropdown

Here's what I am trying to do: If I select something from the dropdown list "selectOption1", I want to set an option in the other dropdown list "selectOption2" to "invisible". Unfortunately, I cannot address the element correctly in the other list.

**multiCapture.html**

```js
function setAnrede() {
  var ddl = document.getElementById("selectOption1");
  var selectedValue1 = ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].value;

  var ddl = document.getElementById("selectOption2");
  var selectedValue2 = ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].value;

  if (selectedValue1 == 'Männlich') {
    selectedValue2.options[2].style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="table-wrapper">
    <div class="table-scroll">
      <table id="myTable">
        <tr>
          <th>Geschlecht</th>
          <th>Anrede</th>
          <th>Titel</th>
          <th>Vorname</th>
          <th>Nachname</th>
          <th>E-Mail</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div class="input-field">
              <select id="selectOption1" required onchange="setAnrede()">
                <option value="Bitte auswählen" selected>Bitte auswählen</option>
                <option value="Männlich">Männlich</option>
                <option value="Weiblich">Weiblich</option>
              </select>
              <label>Geschlecht angeben:</label>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="input-field">
              <select id="selectOption2" required>
                <option value="Bitte auswählen" selected>Bitte auswählen</option>
                <option value="Sehr geehrter">Sehr geehrter</option>
                <option value="Lieber">Lieber</option>
                <option value="Werter">Werter</option>
                <option value="Hallo">Hallo</option>
              </select>
              <label>Anrede angeben:</label>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Are you able to use jQuery?

Comment: Yes, jQuery would be fine :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could attach the `change` event in your JS code instead, then use `eq()` to select the option you want based on the index, like:

**jQuery solution :**

```js
$('#selectOption1').on('change', setAnrede);

function setAnrede() {
  var ddl = $("#selectOption1");
  var dd2 = $("#selectOption2");

  if ($(this).val() === 'Männlich') {
    dd2.find('option:eq(2)').hide();
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div class="table-wrapper">
    <div class="table-scroll">
      <table id="myTable" border=1>
        <tr>
          <th>Geschlecht</th>
          <th>Anrede</th>
          <th>Titel</th>
          <th>Vorname</th>
          <th>Nachname</th>
          <th>E-Mail</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div class="input-field">
              <select id="selectOption1" required>
                <option value="Bitte auswählen" selected>Bitte auswählen</option>
                <option value="Männlich">Männlich</option>
                <option value="Weiblich">Weiblich</option>
              </select>
              <label>Geschlecht angeben:</label>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="input-field">
              <select id="selectOption2" required>
                <option value="Bitte auswählen" selected>Bitte auswählen</option>
                <option value="Sehr geehrter">Sehr geehrter</option>
                <option value="Lieber">Lieber</option>
                <option value="Werter">Werter</option>
                <option value="Hallo">Hallo</option>
              </select>
              <label>Anrede angeben:</label>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

**Pure Js solution**

```js
document.getElementById("selectOption1").addEventListener("click", setAnrede);

function setAnrede() {
  var ddl = document.getElementById("selectOption1");
  var dd2 = document.getElementById("selectOption2");

  var selectedValue1 = ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].value;

  if (selectedValue1 == 'Männlich') {
    dd2.options[2].style.display = "none";
  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div class="table-wrapper">
    <div class="table-scroll">
      <table id="myTable" border=1>
        <tr>
          <th>Geschlecht</th>
          <th>Anrede</th>
          <th>Titel</th>
          <th>Vorname</th>
          <th>Nachname</th>
          <th>E-Mail</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div class="input-field">
              <select id="selectOption1" required>
                <option value="Bitte auswählen" selected>Bitte auswählen</option>
                <option value="Männlich">Männlich</option>
                <option value="Weiblich">Weiblich</option>
              </select>
              <label>Geschlecht angeben:</label>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="input-field">
              <select id="selectOption2" required>
                <option value="Bitte auswählen" selected>Bitte auswählen</option>
                <option value="Sehr geehrter">Sehr geehrter</option>
                <option value="Lieber">Lieber</option>
                <option value="Werter">Werter</option>
                <option value="Hallo">Hallo</option>
              </select>
              <label>Anrede angeben:</label>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I tried both of your solutions. With both, i reach the if loop, but it actually doesn't affect the third element in the other dropdown...

Comment: I just figured out what my problem was. I use materializecss and strangly it affects the functionallity of your solution. I had to add the class "browser-default" to the select tag. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your javascript code

```
<script type="application/x-javascript">

function setAnrede() {
    var ddl = document.getElementById("selectOption1");
    var selectedValue1 = ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].value;

    var ddl2 = document.getElementById("selectOption2");
    var selectedValue2 = ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].value;

    if (selectedValue1 == 'Männlich') {
        ddl2.options[2].style.display = "none";
    }

}
</script>
```